# What's the IIS Equivalent of HTTP_MOD_REWRITE?

Tags: php, iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm installing a PHP web application (BuilderEngine) under IIS, but the URLs for CSS and JS resources aren't being built correctly. Apparently the application is checking to see whether `HTTP_MOD_REWRITE` is enabled.

I've got the URL Rewrite module installed under IIS, of course, but IIS doesn't seem to set the `HTTP_MOD_REWRITE` variable. What's the equivalent for the URL Rewrite Module in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

IIS sets the `IIS_UrlRewriteModule` environment variable when the URL Rewrite module is installed; its value is a string version number.

In PHP this can be accessed as `$_SERVER['IIS_UrlRewriteModule']` just as you'd expect.